# Symfony 5 | liip/imagine-bundle kernel error

Tags: symfony5

Getting the following error when trying to run composer req liip/imagine-bundle.

```
You have requested a non-existent parameter "kernel.secret". Did you mean this: "kernel.charset"?
```

Comment: composer not "just" installs what you requested but will also run scripts, which in turn means if there's a relevant error in your application composer may choke on that. could you please verify that `bin/console cache:clear` works without any error before you run the composer command? also, there's probably a stack trace of where the error occured, which might be very helpful.

Comment: I identified and resolved  the problem: by going to the vendor/liip/imagine-bundle/Resources/config/imagine.xlm. Search for "kernel.secret" and replace with kernel.charset

Answer (score 0):

I identified and resolved  the problem: by going to the vendor/liip/imagine-bundle/Resources/config/imagine.xlm. Search for "kernel.secret" and replace with kernel.charset

Answer (score 0):

The best option to resolve this kind of issues is to add it in the service.yaml of the config.
your_dir/config/services.yaml and add
parameters:
kernel.secret: kernel.secret